# Fastest way to save OpenXML Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, excel, interop

I'm working on a system that, using Interop, reads in a word doc (that acts as a template) and excel document. The program then uses OpenXML to replace keywords in the word doc based on data in the excel document. It then saves the converted document as a pdf. However the process is slow as it uses a lot of read write requests:

- It saves a copy of the template to a directory where the converted files are to go
- It then processes it with the excel data read into a datatable and uses openxml to convert
- It then converts the word file to pdf and deletes the existing word document

It has to do this for each row in the excel document (which is a lot of reads and writes to storage). I was wondering if there is a way to keep the processing in memory? Unfortanutely the openxml library (a modified I use) needs a directory to the actual word doc and can't just use a word doc object.

I'm thinking of doing the deleting on a directory level instead of file level in an attempt to speed it up. I'm not sure how much of a difference this will make.
Are there any blatant optimisations I'm missing?

Comment: Couldn't you save to a memory stream instead of the disk? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee945362(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Hey there, I would like to do that - but the openxml library we use prevents that from being an option. However I'm going to enquire whether or not I'm permitted to modify it

Comment: I read the article (apologies for replying before reading) and it looks viable. I'll give it ago and reply here with my results. Thanks